# Keep Ordering of Bra Ket When Printing

Tags: pattern-matching, slideshows

I would like to keep the ordering of the bra ket-print but right now this doesn't happen. Any Idea? 
I tried playing with HoldForm but then i could evaluate the expression inside properly

```
Ns = 1;
Table[
 (Ket[(Replace[ Quotient[i - 1, Ns], {0 -> "\[UpArrow] ", 
     1 -> "\[DownArrow] "}] <> ToString@Mod[i, Ns])]
  Bra[(Replace[        Quotient[j - 1, Ns], {0 -> "\[UpArrow] ", 
     1 -> "\[DownArrow] "}] <> ToString@Mod[j, Ns])])

, {i, 1, Ns*2}, {j, 1, Ns*2}   ] // MatrixForm
```

Right now this gives:

[image: bad braket]

I would like it to give something more like:

[image: good braket]

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do it entirely without `ToString`. The main tool in combining mixed type output in a given order is [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html):

```
Ns = 1;
Table[Row[
   {
    Ket[Row[{
       Replace[
        Quotient[i - 1, Ns], {0 -> "\[UpArrow] ", 
         1 -> "\[DownArrow] "}], Mod[i, Ns]}]
     ],
    Bra[Row[{Replace[
        Quotient[j - 1, Ns], {0 -> "\[UpArrow] ", 
         1 -> "\[DownArrow] "}], Mod[j, Ns]}]
     ]}],
  {i, 1, Ns*2}, {j, 1, Ns*2}] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  |\text{$\uparrow $ }0\rangle
>    \langle \text{$\uparrow $ }0| &
>    |\text{$\uparrow $ }0\rangle
>    \langle \text{$\downarrow $ }0|
>    \\
>  |\text{$\downarrow $ }0\rangle
>    \langle \text{$\uparrow $ }0| &
>    |\text{$\downarrow $ }0\rangle
>    \langle \text{$\downarrow $ }0|
>    \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Edit to elaborate on comment**

In the long run, it may be better to separate the formatting from the algebra. To that end, I would first observe that there is an algebraic reason for the order of the bra and ket to be maintained. You're really forming something that in a matrix representation corresponds to non-commutative multiplication. So it makes sense to enter these bras and kets with a specially defined multiplication symbol, say, `\[CenterDot]` -- the $\cdot$ symbol. This symbol has no pre-defined meaning and allows you to tailor any output format for it that you like. That is, you input a "multiplication" with $\cdot$ but we can set it up to *output* the product without explicit multiplication symbol. Moreover, if the labels of the kets and bras are always a spin arrow and a number, you can predefine that in a `Format` statement too:

```
arrows = {0 -> "\[UpArrow]", 1 -> "\[DownArrow]"};
Format[Ket[x_, y_]] := Ket@Row[{x /. arrows, "\[ThinSpace]", y}];
Format[Bra[x_, y_]] := Bra@Row[{x /. arrows, "\[ThinSpace]", y}];
Format[CenterDot[x__]] := Row[Riffle[{x}, "\[ThinSpace]"]];

Ns = 1;
Table[
  Ket[
    Quotient[i - 1, Ns], Mod[i, Ns]
    ]\[CenterDot]Bra[
    Quotient[j - 1, Ns], Mod[j, Ns]
    ],
  {i, 1, Ns*2}, {j, 1, Ns*2}] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

The point here is that where it says `\[CenterDot]` in the code, I actually only had to enter the shortcut <kbd>Esc</kbd>`.`<kbd>Esc</kbd>. So the ordered product is now very easy to enter, and the actual algebraic expression is much easier to read.

I again used `Row` for formatting, combined with `\[ThinSpace]` as a spacer between elements of the bras and kets, as well as in the product.

Comment: That is quite useful. Are there any other good commands relevant to this I should look at too?  Thank you Jens

Comment: @AimForClarity Yes, the formatting could be separated further from the content, to improve readablilty. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good tip. I have been defining  matrices to represent the algebra of a number space and a "qubit" space for a random walk by using the kronecker product. I wonder if instead I used the algebra and defined the non-commutative operations on the bra-ket row structure via the \cdot, if that would have been a better approach. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AimForClarity Actually, I'd say your approach sounds just fine. For a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, bras and kets are completely analogous to row- and column vectors in a vector space defined by some working basis, and then you may as well leverage the built-in capabilities for matrix multiplication, instead of re-implementing the corresponding algebra symbolically. That's also how I've done it before.

Comment: Thanks Jens. I have also used the http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/ package but found it slow for any useful work. There they define all the associated operations on bra and kets

Comment: Yes, instead of using a package for this kind of manipulation, I prefer to make my own (and have done so) to retain more control of the features I care about. Ultimately it's all just linear algebra with some formatting.

Comment: @AimForClarity just to add to what Jens said, using explicit matrix/vector representations is also what I do for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. It's more convenient than defining the algebra and, if you need it, it scales to large-dimensional spaces easily.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just figured out a simple minded solution, but I hope that someone has a more elegant one perhaps.

Basically you can just use StringReplace & use string all the way

```
  Clear@i1
  Table[
  HS2[[i, j]]*
    StringReplace[
     "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"row\"},\n\"Ket\"]\)\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"col\
   \"},\n\"Bra\"]\)", {"row" -> ( (Replace[
      Quotient[i - 1, Ns], {0 -> "\[UpArrow] ", 
       1 -> "\[DownArrow] "}] <> ToString@Mod[i, Ns])),
 "col" -> (Replace[
     Quotient[j - 1, Ns], {0 -> "\[UpArrow] ", 
      1 -> "\[DownArrow] "}] <> ToString@Mod[j, Ns])

 }]
 , {i, 1, Dimensions[HS2, 1][[1]]}, {j, 1, 
 Dimensions[HS2, 2][[1]]}   ] // MatrixForm
```

An Example output:

[image: out]

To turn into nice representation:

[image: out2]